# Python: adding row in table with value of 1st and 2nd group-ranked variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have data that is grouped and has a value associated with it. I'm fine with working out the rank of each value within its subgroup -

```py
df['Rank'] = df.groupby('Group')['Value'].rank(ascending=True)
```

However, I'd also like to create an additional column that shows the top-ranked value and second-ranked value within each group as a separate column - i.e. in the image attached below (I've not worked out how to draw a table on this website yet!). Many thanks.

#### Data Table

[image: Data Table]

Comment: Please don't post data as image, we can not copy the content from image. Take a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the [Minimal Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) also [How to make good reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get unique rank values for each group

   ```
   group_data = df[['Group','Rank']].drop_duplicates()
   ```
2. Get rank 1 and rank 2 data

   ```
    group_rank_1 = group_data.loc[group_data.Rank==1,'Value']
    group_rank_1.columns=['Group','GroupRank1Value']

    group_rank_2 = group_data.loc[group_data.Rank==2,'Value']
    group_rank_1.columns=['Group','GroupRank2Value']
   ```
3. Join with the original data frame

   ```
   res = df.merge(group_rank_1,how='inner', on='Group')
   res = res.merge(group_rank_2,how='inner', on='Group')
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm a bit confused by this - which of the steps here is passing on the Value of the rank 1 and rank 2 before it's joined back to the table? When I follow these instructions I just get two additional columns full of 1s and then 2s? Maybe I'm misinterpreting your instructions...?